# Chrome addon, extension or hack to open whatsapp web with phone numbers found in the internet

Tags: whatsapp

My businesses currently relies heavily on whatsapp to communicate with our guests, we send receipts, daily info, we do pre-check ins etc etc.

we need a way to be able to click the guest's phone number and that this will open the whatsapp web app with the number clicked,

currently we are doing this manually (copy, edit number, paste), but we want to speed up the process.

Do you remember that pesky Skype add on that it would add the ability to Skype any number found on a website? is something like that.

things that i have tried.

- Change the callto: and tel: association, but this relies on an external app and not a website.
- greasemonkey (but my code fu no good)

thank you all.